# The getter 'length' isn't defined for the type 'List<Meals> Function({bool growable})'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am learning flutter and following a tutorial I exactly copied his code but due to some reason I am facing this error in my code which states as follows

```
class categoryMealsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/category-meal';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final routeArgs =
        ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String, String>;
    final categoryTitle = routeArgs['title'];
    final categoryId = routeArgs['id'];
    final categoryMeals = DUMMY_MEALS.where((meal) {
      return meal.categories.contains(categoryId);
    }).toList;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(categoryTitle!),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
          return Text(categoryTitle);
        },
        **itemCount: categoryMeals.length,**
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `toList` to `toList()`.

```dart
final categoryMeals = DUMMY_MEALS.where((meal) { 
  return meal.categories.contains(categoryId);
   }).toList;
```